# How to write json format in C# string?

Tags: c#, json, string

How i cab write a json format in C# string:

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string strNJson = @"{to:'topics/extrafx',notification:{title:{0},text:{1},sound: 'default'}}";

            strNJson = string.Format(strNJson, not_title, not_body);
            streamWriter.Write(strNJson);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }
```

Please advice?

Comment: Json is the text serialisation of an object. So you simply have to create an object with those property and serialise it.

Comment: What issue are you facing? Have you looked at serializing using something like Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: Try using Newtonsoft's json Serializer,

Comment: This is invalid JSON. You should use `@"{ ""to"": ""topics/extrafx"", ""notification"": { ""title"": ""{0}"", ""text"": ""{1}"", ""sound"": ""default"" } }"`, so the result will be `{ "to": "topics/extrafx", "notification": { "title": "<placeholder>", "text": "<placeholder>", "sound": "default" } }"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Json is the text serialisation of an object. So you simply have to create an object with those property and serialise it. To assit in creating the class that represent your object you can simply paste a Valid Json to [Json 2 C#](http://json2csharp.com/).

```
public class Notification
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string sound { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string to { get; set; }
    public Notification notification { get; set; }
}
```

And use it like :

```
var item = new RootObject {
    to = "topics/extrafx",
    notification = new Notification  {
        title = variableFoo,
        text = variableBar,
        sound = "default"

    }
};
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
```

Comment: You can also generate the classes in Visual Studio: Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes

Comment: @yaakov, I also favor this method but I can't assume that one have Visual studio or a version of visual studio that can do this. With external website there is little to no excuse. i must have at least 20 comment exactly like yours ;)

Comment: @YusufShayah, sorry I droped the quote around default. It's edidted now. 
Or do you mean you need the property to have a default value like `public string sound { get; set; } = "default";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this version:

```
string not_title, not_body;
not_title = "title";
not_body = "body";  
string strNJson = @"{{'to':'topics/extrafx','notification':{{'title':'{0}','text':'{1}','sound': 'default'}}}}";

strNJson = string.Format(strNJson, not_title, not_body);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private const string DATA = @"{
                    ""uuid"": ""27c0f81c-23bc-4878-a6a5-49da58cd30dr"",
                    ""status"": ""Work"",
                    ""job_address"": ""Somewhere"",
                    ""job_description"": ""Just a Test API CALL, John Mckinley's Job""}";
```

"" Calling the Data to this one

```
content = new StringContent(DATA, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

You can try this.